# Spring boot ware deployment on private JVM, unable to hit controllers

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I build a backend app using spring boot, I purchased a hosting in mochahost with private JVM, after deploying the war file I cannot hit my mapped controllers.

In mochahost when deploying WAR (using deploy WAR option) the WAR file is uploaded to location `"/jvm/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/domains/[mydomain]/ "` then I run tomcat and the webapp is extracted in the same location , webapp is my WAR file name

my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

also I created a servlet initialized class

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
}

 }
```

the controller im trying to hit is:

```
  @RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductsController {

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(productService.getAllProducts(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the url im trying to access htttp://[mydomain]/webapp/products, but im getting `404 page not found`, any help is appreciated

Comment: did you try htttp://[mydomain]/products?

Comment: yeah I did but did not work aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue , the problem was that the servlet initializer is not the main application class, I made them one class and the issue is gone.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
}
}
```